# Vue iterated data not showing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I created vue pages to show data from my json file. I'm now having trouble with getting the data to show on my page.

In my mainContainerContent I put this: `<p>{{ skill.frontend.name }} </p>` inside my p element and I expect this result: [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7x0o.png). But I'm not getting any data back.

When I change it to this: `<p>{{ skill.name }} </p>` I will get this result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB4Bq.png) but I'm still not getting the data from my json file.

**mainContainer.vue:**

```
<template>
  <Skills v-for="skill in skills.skills" :skill="skill" :key="skill.id"/>
</template>

<script setup>
  import Skills from './mainContainerSkills.vue';

  import skills from "../Skills.json";
</script>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    skills: {
      default: null,
      type: Object,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**mainContainerSkills.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Frontend -->
    <div>
      <h3>
        Frontend
      </h3>
      <p>{{ skill.frontend.name }} </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Backend -->
    <div>
      <h3>
        Backend
      </h3>
      <p>{{ skill.backend.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    skill: {
      default: null,
      type: Object,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Skills.json:**

```
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "skills",
      "frontend": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Vue",
          "icon": "Vue"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "HTML",
          "icon": "HTML"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Javascript",
          "icon": "Javascript"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Tailwind",
          "icon": "Tailwind"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "name": "Bootstrap",
          "icon": "Bootstrap"
        }
      ],
      "backend": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Laravel",
          "icon": "Laravel"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "PHP",
          "icon": "PHP"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I solve this problem so that I can show the data from the frontend and backend object?

Playground: https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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

Comment: Could you please make a playground on https://play.vuejs.org/ ? Then answering would be a lot easier

Comment: `{{ text displays }}` support JSON, so I recommend using them to display what you have to debug easily

Comment: @Dimava Hi, I wanted to make a playground but it doesnt support json files

Comment: in such cases I generally inline data into JS (JS supports JSON inline after all)

Comment: @Dimava I edited the question and added a playground

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how it can be made, and here is how it's easy to display values for debugging purposes (it should be removed after finishing)
(p changed into list for visibility)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Frontend -->
    <div>
      <code>skill.frontend={{skill.frontend}}</code>
      <h3>
        Frontend
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="fe in skill.frontend">
          {{fe.name}}
          <br> li json={{ fe }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Backend -->
    <div>
      <code>skill.backend={{skill.backend}}</code>
      <h3>
        Backend
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="be in skill.backend">
          {{be.name}}
          <br> li json={{ be }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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

Answer (score 0):

First, you have the data in the json file organized incorrectly (redid it).

Second, follow upl where you import components and other data from.

Third, your example has a bunch of mistakes in it, so I reworked it for you to look at and maybe have learned something useful for themselves.

Best regards! ✌️

[**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: @clipyz I also thought about this, can your data be malformed, or it's intended to be that way?

Comment: @Dimava The data could be malformed, didnt think about something like this myself